# Android TextView cuts off after one paragraph

Tags: java, android, textview

I am creating an app for my school newspaper and am running into a problem when trying to display the full article. Currently I have a list of articles appear that are pulled from an RSS feed, and when one is clicked on it brings up the content of the article. However only the first paragraph displays in the TextView, no matter how long it is. This leads me too believe that it has something to do with the `<p></p>` HTML tags. I am not that familiar with RSS feeds or parsing XML(this being my first time trying it)and have looked around for ways to do what I'm trying to accomplish.

I am basing this project off of a series of posts from this blog: http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/04/simple-rss-reader-in-listview.html

I took the project provided here and have added it to a tabs with swipe template and changed how some of the elements are laid out.

DISCLAMER: There is a lot of commented ugly code that I was too lazy to take out. It is mostly stuff I didn't want in the layout.
Here is the Fragment that contains the list of articles:

```
public class AllStoriesFragment extends ListFragment {

    /*********************************************************************
     * RSS Async Task
     *********************************************************************/
    public class RssLoadingTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            displayRss();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            preReadRss();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            readRss();
            return null;
        }

    }
    /*********************************************************************
     * End RSS Async Task
     *********************************************************************/

    private RSSFeed myRssFeed = null;

    TextView feedTitle;
    TextView feedDescription;
    //TextView feedPubdate;
    TextView feedLink;
    //TextView feedContent;

    /*********************************************************************
     * Custom Array Adapter 
     *********************************************************************/
    public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RSSItem> {
        public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                List<RSSItem> list) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, list);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            View row = convertView;

            if(row==null){
                LayoutInflater inflater=getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
                row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
            }

            TextView listTitle=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.listtitle);
            listTitle.setText(myRssFeed.getList().get(position).getTitle());
            TextView listPubdate=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.listpubdate);
            listPubdate.setText(myRssFeed.getList().get(position).getPubdate());

            if (position%2 == 0){
                listTitle.setBackgroundColor(0xff101010);
                listPubdate.setBackgroundColor(0xff101010);
            }
            else{
                listTitle.setBackgroundColor(0xff080808);
                listPubdate.setBackgroundColor(0xff080808);
            }

            return row;
        }
    }
    /*********************************************************************
     * End Custom Array Adapter 
     *********************************************************************/

   /** Called when the fragment is first created. */
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_allstories, null);;

        feedTitle = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.feedtitle);
        feedDescription = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.feeddescription);
        //feedPubdate = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.feedpubdate);
        feedLink = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.feedlink);
        startReadRss();

        return v ;
    }

   private void startReadRss(){
       new RssLoadingTask().execute();
   }

   private void preReadRss(){
       setListAdapter(null);

       Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Reading RSS, Please wait.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }

   private void readRss(){
       try {
           URL rssUrl = new URL("http://www.campusslate.com/feed/");
           SAXParserFactory mySAXParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
           SAXParser mySAXParser = mySAXParserFactory.newSAXParser();
           XMLReader myXMLReader = mySAXParser.getXMLReader();
           RSSHandler myRSSHandler = new RSSHandler();
           myXMLReader.setContentHandler(myRSSHandler);
           InputSource myInputSource = new InputSource(rssUrl.openStream());
           myXMLReader.parse(myInputSource);

           myRssFeed = myRSSHandler.getFeed();
       } 
       catch (MalformedURLException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
       } 
       catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
       } 
       catch (SAXException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
       } 
       catch (IOException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }

   private void displayRss(){

       if (myRssFeed!=null){

           MyCustomAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.row, myRssFeed.getList());
           setListAdapter(adapter);
       }
   }


   public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ShowDetails.class);
   intent.putExtra("keyPubdate", myRssFeed.getItem(position).getPubdate());
   intent.putExtra("keyLink", myRssFeed.getItem(position).getLink());
   intent.putExtra("keyTitle", myRssFeed.getItem(position).getTitle());
   intent.putExtra("keyContent", myRssFeed.getItem(position).getContent());
       startActivity(intent);
   }

   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Reload");
       return true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       switch(item.getItemId()){
       case (0): startReadRss();
       break;
       default:
           break;
       }
       return true;
   }  
}
```

And this is the activity started when an item in the list is clicked:

```
package com.nick.pocketslate;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ShowDetails extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.details);
        TextView detailsTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.detailstitle);
        TextView detailsPubdate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.detailspubdate);
        TextView detailsLink = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.detailslink);
        TextView detailsContent = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.detailscontent);



        Intent intent = getIntent();
    detailsTitle.setText(intent.getStringExtra("keyTitle"));
    detailsPubdate.setText(intent.getStringExtra("keyPubdate"));
    detailsLink.setText(intent.getStringExtra("keyLink"));
    detailsContent.setText(Html.fromHtml(intent.getStringExtra("keyContent")));

    detailsContent.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

    }
}
```

At this point I have done a lot of searching and have not found a solution, and I am not sure what part of my code could be causing the problem. I have a link to download my full project here if anyone can take a look and find the problem.

If anyone has some idea of where to start looking I will put up that section of code.

https://lh.rs/zbdYev99O1G5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've shown looks correct, but where's the code for your model - RSSFeed? You may want to get some debug output that shows whether your RSS-reading is behaving properly. Maybe you're only getting the summary instead of the full article? Maybe the full article should be read from its own link, not from the abridged RSS feed?

For HTML content, you generally go with the [LinkMovementMethod](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/LinkMovementMethod.html), so links in the content are handled properly. TextViews scroll automatically, assuming you haven't set a TextView.maxLines property (may want to check that).

Also, for simplicity, you should just add/read your data directly from the Intent - there's really no need to go through an intermediary Bundle. [putExtra(String,String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) and [getStringExtra(String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getStringExtra%28java.lang.String%29) or you can use their CharSequence equivalents, depending on what exactly is output from RSSReader.

**EDIT:** Are you checking that the TextView scrolls normally displaying dummy text that's longer than 5 lines? You could also try externally copying the Content data from your feed (via an external feed reader) and explicitly putting it in your TextView using [TextView.setText(CharSequence)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) to check whether something in the feed itself is causing your problem.

(Html.fromHtml is based on TagSoup, which is designed to handle even poorly-formed HTML, but you can always try to test with plain-text and see if that works. You can also use the debug log/LogCat to check the before/after of HTML-parsing your RSS feed content.)

If those things have a problem, then it may be an issue with your TextView layout/initialization. If those things all work, then you know the problem is somewhere in your RSS-related code.

Can you post your layout code for the detail view? Also, are you using the emulator or an actual phone? Sometimes the emulator doesn't respond to scrolling gestures quite the same way as an actual device.

**EDIT:** If it's the RSSHandler that's the problem, I'd suggest creating a separate/new question tagged appropriately (SAX, XML-Parser, RSS). If you post a link here to that new question, I can try to help over there. You can also try first looking for specific answers that might help with the SAX approach to XML parsing. Here's a good tutorial I've been using lately - http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-xml/sax.html

Comment: As far as what I'm getting from the feed, it was originally designed to only pull the description element, but I modified it to pull the full article which was under a content:encoded element. I am sure I am pulling the right thing there. I have tried many different methods to make the TextView scroll but I don't think that's the issue since it will only display a 5 sentence paragraph from a large article that doesn't even take up half the screen. As far a the bundle goes, that was how the original author did it so I never changed it.

Comment: I tried it by inserting plain text into the TextView and it scrolled fine. So I guess the problem is in the RSS code. I am testing on an emulator right now, I can try it on my phone later. Here is the code for my ShowDetails.java: http://pastebin.com/Y7fALE6N

Comment: After reviewing my code again I fell like the problem must be in my RSSHandler class but I don't see anything obviously wrong to me. Can someone take a look? http://pastebin.com/ba1aWd4x

Comment: Nothing jumps out - I think you're going to have to add some debugging output and just step through it to find where the problem lies. If you're using Eclipse, the Debug view is your friend...

Comment: After adding some debugging code to my RSSHandler it seems that a lot of RSSItem and RSSFeed fields are not being set as they should. I also tried using CharSequences instead of Strings(didn't think that would change anything), and I tried using the intent instead of the bundle but I am not sure if I am doing that right, how would you implement that?

Comment: Can't seem to view your code via the link above, but the code you've posted above using Intent.putExtra/.getStringExtra is just fine. The only change I might make would be to make your "keys" public static constants, so you can reference them between different activities/classes.

Comment: I posted a new question with relevant code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14588167/android-rss-reader-cuts-off-after-first-pragraph